# Two different PcbDoc in one PrjPcb in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, altium

I created a PrjPcb with two different PcbDocs. I have completed the first PcbDoc, and now I want to replace one of the chip in the schematic and design a new PCB.

I'm making a variant of the chip I want to remove, but the pads of the chip are still on the PCB. How can I design the second PCB by replacing one of the chip in a single project? I want the new chip and the old chip to appear in the schematic.

Comment: Don't use two PCBs. Use the Variants system.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I tried using a variant, but the pads of the other chip appear on the PCB. I want to remove the pads of the old chip. I just want the new chip to appear on the PCB. After updating the schematic to the PCB, I thought of deleting the components that I do not want in the circuit, but I think it will give an error in DRC

Comment: I guess the only solution is to create a new project and copy the old project's files. So I can change the circuit

Comment: No, one last thing: take a look at the OutJob, there's a variant option for Gerber generation etc. I've not used it myself but it may solve that.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Unfortunately, I have to deal with this before coming to the outjob process. Because I don't have enough space on the PCB and I have to remove the chip before I start routing.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.